# Task wont run parallel using OpenMP. Is my setup or my code wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading, task, openmp

I am using OpenMP successful to parallelize for loops in my c++ code. I tried to
step further and use OpenMP tasks. Unfortunately my code behaves
really strange, so i wrote a minimal example and found a problem.
I would like to define a couple of tasks. Each task should be executed once 
by an idle thread.
Unfortunately i can only make all threads execute every task or 
only one thread performing all tasks sequentially.

Here is my code which basically runs sequentially:

```
int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int id, nths;
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            #pragma omp task
            cout<<"My id is "<<id<<endl;
            #pragma omp task
            cout<<"My id is "<<id<<endl;
            #pragma omp task
            cout<<"My id is "<<id<<endl;
            #pragma omp task
            cout<<"My id is "<<id<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Only worker 0 shows up and gives his id four times.
I expected to see "My id is 0; My id is 1; my id is 2; my id is 3;
If i delete `#pragma omp single` i get 16 messages, all threads execute
every single `cout`.

Is this a problem with my OpenMP setup or did I not get something about
tasks? I am using gcc 6.3.0 on Ubuntu and use `-fopenmp` flag properly.

Comment: Single means each task should be approached only by one task. So each Thread should approach one of the tasks.

Comment: But how to get each Task approached by a single thread in parallel?

Comment: @tobi303, `parallel` (start a team of threads) - `single` (one thread is responsible to create the tasks) - `task` (independent execution) is a standard pattern in OpenMP.

Comment: @Zulan so the documentation I linked is wrong? I dont know, thats just what I found and maybe I misunderstood it...

Comment: @tobi303 the doc is correct, but you also have look at the documentation for the `task` construct to understand the combination.

Comment: @Zulan hm ok I have to do some rtfm ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic usage of OpenMP tasks (`parallel` -> `single` -> `task`) is correct, you misunderstand the intricacies of data-sharing attributes for variables.

First, you can easily confirm that your tasks are run by different threads by moving `omp_get_thread_num()` inside the task instead of accessing `id`.

What happens in your example, `id` becomes implicitly `private` within the `parallel` construct. However, inside the task, it becomes implicitly `firstprivate`. This means, the task copies the value from the thread that executes the `single` construct. A more elaborate discussion of a similar issue [can be found here](http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=912&start=0).

Note that if you used `private` within a nested task construct, it would not be the same `private` variable as the one of the outside parallel construct. Simply said, `private` does not refer to the thread, but the construct. That's the difference to `threadprivate`. However, `threadprivate` is not an attribute to a construct, but it's own directive and only applies to variables with file-scope, namespace-scope or static variables with block-scope.